# How to uninstall Draftsight in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I install draftsight in 12.04 but it the display does not appear. Pls help me how to fix it or uninstaall the draftsight.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The package has been renamed, so in 14.04 you can just do:

> sudo dpkg -r draftsight

Answer (score 2):

You must run this in a terminal

```
sudo dpkg -r dassault-systemes-draftsight
```

Comment: when I try the above I get error: dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching dassault-systems-draftsight but I have the draftsight command available and ubuntu tries to open some extensions with draftsight